# full screen sliding div in different sizes and direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

I've been trying to make full screen responsive sliding div elements in different directions and sizes and I've found this method through here.

http://jsfiddle.net/jkDUm/

```
$(document).click(function () {
$(".page").toggleClass("in");
});
```

And this is what I'm trying to do.

```
    <span id="button">open slider 1</span>
    <span id="button2">open slider 2</span>
    <span id="button3">open slider 3</span>

    <div id="slider">
        <span id="button4">close</span>
    </div>

    <div id="slider2">
        <span id="button5">close</span>      
    </div>

    <div id="slider3">
        <span id="button6">close</span>     
    </div>
```

- Button 1, 2, 3 will be the words in a paragraph.
- "slider" will slide down from the top with 100% width and 50% height.
- "slider2" will slide to the left from right with 50% width and 100% height.
- "slider3" will slide up from the bottom with 100% and 100% height.
- each slide has own close button simply to move the slides back.

This image also displays what I'm trying to do. click [here](http://www.ejkimdesign.com/slide_examples.jpg)

Thanks for reading this and hope someone can help me to build this.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this help?? http://www.jongaulin.com/2011/11/17/fullscreen-image-and-content-slider/

Comment: Thanks Rahul. This is awesome slider but I'm not trying to make a image gallery slider. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkDUm/5/)

**JS**

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#slider').addClass('in');
});

$('#button2').click(function(){
    $('#slider2').addClass('in');
});

$('#button3').click(function(){
    $('#slider3').addClass('in');
});

$('#button4').click(function(){
    $('#slider').removeClass('in');
});

$('#button5').click(function(){
    $('#slider2').removeClass('in');
});

$('#button6').click(function(){
    $('#slider3').removeClass('in');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="height:100%">
<span id="button">open slider 1</span>

<span id="button2">open slider 2</span>

<span id="button3">open slider 3</span>

    <div id="slider"> <span id="button4">close</span>

    </div>
    <div id="slider2"> <span id="button5">close</span> 
    </div>
    <div id="slider3"> <span id="button6">close</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
}
.page.in {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#slider {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    bottom: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    transition: bottom 1s;
}
#slider.in {
    bottom:50%;
}
#slider2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    left:100%;
    top:0;
    background: red;
    transition: left 1s;
}
#slider2.in {
    left:50%;
}
#slider3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:100%;
    background: blue;
    transition: top 1s;
}
#slider3.in {
    top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to establish 2 css classes for each slider div, one for when it is display and one for when it is not.  Then your codes is as simple as change the class of the elements when the button is clicked.

One possibility:

```
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider.top {
    top: -50%;
    left: 0px;
    transition: top 1s;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.slider.top.in {
    top: 0%;
}

.slider.right {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    transition: left 1s;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background: yellow;
}

.slider.right.in {
    left: 50%;
}

.slider.bottom {
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    transition: top 1s;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    color: cyan;
}

.slider.bottom.in {
    top: 50%;
}
```

query

```
$("#button").click(function(){$("#slider").addClass("in");});
$("#button2").click(function(){$("#slider2").toggleClass("in");});
$("#button3").click(function(){$("#slider3").toggleClass("in");});
$(".closebutton").click(function(){$(this).parent().removeClass("in");});
```

html

```
<p><span id="button">open slider 1</span></p>
<p><span id="button2">open slider 2</span></p>
<p><span id="button3">open slider 3</span></p>

<div id="slider" class="top slider">
    <span id="button4" class="closebutton">close</span>
</div>

<div id="slider2" class="right slider">
    <span id="button5" class="closebutton">close</span>      
</div>

<div id="slider3" class="bottom slider">
    <span id="button6" class="closebutton">close</span>     
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tSSNy/)